# How to add Custom Context Menu to Text Area Control in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am using the following codes to declare a Text Area:

```
<s:TextArea id="txtArea" width="{this.width}" height="{this.height}" borderVisible="false" focusAlpha="0.01" selectionHighlighting="always" styleName="scrollableText"needsSoftKeyboard="true" focusRect="false" direction="{textBoxDirction}" buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" mouseChildren="true"/>
```

I want to add a Custom Context Menu to this Text Area and to add Custom Context Menu i am using following codes:

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
contextMenu.clipboardMenu = false;
contextMenu.addItem(new ContextMenuItem("Start Select"));
contextMenu.addItem(new ContextMenuItem("Start Copy"));

txtArea.contextMenu = contextMenu;
```

But my problem is that after adding this also in first right click i am getting the default Context Menu, i.e
[image]

And from second right click i am getting my Custom Context Menu, i.e
[image]

I am unable to know why i am not getting the Custom Context Menu from first right click.

So if anybody can find where i am doing wrong or how to resolve this problem please help me to solve.

Comment: you must create your own textarea class then looking to right mouse down event, to display a custom context menu, is that easy? No,  is that impossible? No.

Comment: @payam sbr I think you are missing the point here. Displaying a custom context menu was already achieved and a custom class is not necessary for that. The question is why the menu shows up differently the first time it shows up.

Comment: Hi @payamsbr I think you are unable to understood my question, My question is that why i am getting default context menu in my first right click instead of getting custom context menu because i have already added the custom context menu to my textArea component and which is showing from second right click.

Answer (score 0):

The Following codes resolved my problem:

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
contextMenu.clipboardMenu = false;
contextMenu.addItem(new ContextMenuItem("Start Select"));
contextMenu.addItem(new ContextMenuItem("Start Copy"));

(txtArea.textDisplay as RichEditableText).contextMenu = contextMenu;
```

Instead of putting custom context menu directly into **textArea** control, if we will put on **richEditableText** as above then that will solve this problem.